# Has anyone fixed the problem of Nativescript plugin for VS code hanging when trying to launch debugger on iOS?

Tags: ios, debugging, visual-studio-code, plugins, nativescript

Since a few weeks ago my Nativescript plugin for VS Code hangs when trying to debug with 'Launch on iOS'.  'Launch on Android' works perfectly.

I can still run 'tns debug ios' in a terminal and 'Attach on iOS' OK, but source updates subsequently takes a very long time to detect changes and re-sync.  I can generally only make 2 or 3 code changes before having to kill and relaunch from the terminal in frustration.

'Launch on iOS' worked fine for years, but stopped around the same time as an update to Catalina 10.15.5 and an Xcode update to 11.5.

NativeScript plugin version is 0.11.0, tns version is 6.7.4, VS Code is 1.46.0.

Output is:
[NativeScriptCli] execute: tns --analyticsClient VSCode --version
[NSDebugAdapter] Using tns CLI v6.7.4 on path 'tns'

[NSDebugAdapter] Running tns command...

(whereupon nothing else happens and have to kill by clicking the red debug square.)

Answer (score 1):

OK, eventually fixed this myself by reading the `nativescript-vscode-extension` plugin source to get a hint.

I had more than one Apple developer team account and needed to identify the `teamId` to use in `launch.json`.  The plugin was unable to determine `teamId` from any other source.

Also needed to specify the simulator name.  Adding this property to `Launch on iOS` configuration in `launch.json` fixed the problem.

```
"tnsArgs": [
    "--emulator", "iPhone 6",
    "--teamId", "xxxxxxxxxx"
]
```

Hope this helps somebody.